# pg_archivecleanup command not found

Tags: postgresql, archive

I have standby db. I get this log.

```
WARNING:  archive_cleanup_command "pg_archivecleanup /var/lib/pgsql/archivedir %r": command not found
sh: pg_archivecleanup: command not found
WARNING:  archive_cleanup_command "pg_archivecleanup /var/lib/pgsql/archivedir %r": command not found
sh: pg_archivecleanup: command not found
```

But i never settings postgres.conf about "archive_cleanup_command".
And OS path settings have postgresql path.

Why i get that error log?
And what should i go?

Thank you.

I searched about my problem. But still i don't understand.